# How can I check that AntiSamy is working on my CQ instance?

Tags: java, integration, xss, aem, antisamy

I am investigating how to integrate AntiSamy with CQ5. My steps so far are to:

1. Checked that the CQ instance contains a file at this CRX path `/libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml`, which defines the configuration of AntiSamy.
2. Download the [3rd-party bundle (esapi 2.0GA)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.esapi/2.0GA_1) and install it to CQ. After this step, the bundle is in an `installed` state (not `active`).
3. To activate the bundle above, I installed this list of dependencies:

   - [AntiSamy v1.4.5_1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.antisamy/1.4.5_1)
   - [Commons BeanUtils v1.8.3_2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-beanutils/1.8.3_2)
   - [Commons Configuration v1.4_4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-configuration/1.4_4)
   - [Xerces v2.11.0_1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xerces/2.11.0_1)
   - [XML Resolver v1.2_1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver/1.2_1)

**My questions:**

1. Does CQ5 provides an entire package for integration that I may
   download as one complete package and AntiSamy will work?
2. How do I check that AntiSamy is working? What signs should I notice?
3. Do I need to write any Java code (e.g. related to HTML filtering) or
   CQ5 invoke it without any effort?

Answer (score 0):

`AntiSamy` lib is embedded into `cq-xssprotection` bundle and used by it's services, in 5.5 version as well as in 5.6. Decompilation of this jar proved that they use `cq/xssprotection/config` configuration from `/libs` or `/apps` if it's overlay.

my cq instance has already contained cq-xssprotection bundle. If you don't have it out of the box you can try download it from [this adobe repository link](http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/cq/cq-xssprotection/5.4.0/)

The information related with question number 3: I have read this topic [adobe forum link](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4481711) and I can make resolution that I should write java code uses XSSAPI.

How to write this code?

I have found this [xss Cheat Sheet](http://eyelock-cdn-blog.eyelock.net.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/xss_cheat_sheet.pdf)

### update

cq-xssprotection bundle pom.xml fragment:

```
...
<name>Day Communique 5 XSS Protection</name>
<description>
    CQ5 platform bundle for providing XSS protection using the AntiSamy library.
</description>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
       <artifactId>antisamy</artifactId>
       <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
...
```